# How to use navigator.onLine feature to POST from a form to a PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to use the navigator.onLine to check whether the browser is Online or Offline. Now if i want to POST a form HTML to a PHP based on this condition, what is the possible way to do so. Below is the code for the same.

HTML

```
<script>
var online = navigator.onLine;
if(online){
function PostData() {


    // 1. Create XHR instance - Start
    var xhr;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    // 1. Create XHR instance - End

    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var pid = document.getElementById("pid").value;
    // var image = document.getElementById("image").value;
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 


    xhr.open('POST', 'login.php');
    //xhr.open('POST', 'config.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("userid=" + userid + "&pid=" + pid);
    //xhr.send("&pid=" + pid);
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End

}
}
</script>
```